When I don't pull the previous slide in the swiper, it appears half in front of the active one

When navigating to the last slide in my Swiper slider, it currently becomes the active item as expected. However, I want to achieve a seamless looping effect where, upon reaching the last slide, the navigation automatically transitions back to the first slide, making it the active item. Essentially, I want the slider to create a continuous loop, so users don’t experience any breaks or gaps when cycling through the slides. How can I configure Swiper to ensure this smooth looping functionality, making the first slide active immediately after reaching the last one?
.slide_media .swiper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.slide_media .swiper-wrapper {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 359px;
    position: relative;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 317px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateY(40px);
    transition: 0.3s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide-active {
    width: 100%;
    height: 357px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide-active::after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('assets/images/play.svg');
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 1;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active)::after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('assets/images/play.svg');
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide .overlay_title {
    background: #D1DFEA;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide .overlay_title h4 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #111331;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active) .overlay_title {
    display: none;
}

.slide_media .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active .overlay_title {
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}```

